# How can I set nanosecond precision mtime in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can get nanosecond precision mtime by passing `{bigint: true}` as the second argument to `fs.stat` and I can set mtime via `fs.utimes`, but no matter what type I pass to `fs.utimes`, it only ends up writing second precision.